# Apache/htaccess set Remote_Addr with custom ipaddress for test/debug rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want test an htaccess rule based on `Remote_Addr`:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^192\.168\.1\.(?:19[2-9]|2[0-5][0-9])$" FOO=BAR
```

I can set `Remote_Addr` with some custom value, for test/debug my rule? i have tried:

```
SetEnv Remote_Addr=110.80.XXX.XX
```

but dosn't work.

*side note: it's also good for me if i can do this via Apache configurations...*

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? That would be better explained because that might not be the best way to do it.

Comment: `REMOTE_ADDR` is a server variable - you can't simply overwrite it (in order to "test"). You could only do this by "hacking" the request. And if you did do this you won't get a response. I suggest you test this by using something other than `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: @PanamaJack i have update my question.